# How to design constant current source for MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet, ac, pwm

I am trying to design a single phase AC motor driver, using a MOSFET for this purpose, you know how it is shown approximately in the figure:

[image]

But I was thinking that it would be a good idea to place a constant current source to charge the gate capacitor of the MOSFET, but I feel that a simple transistor in series with the gate would not be the solution, does anyone know how I could make the circuit I want? I will show an approximate drawing of what I want to do.

[image]

(The values ​​that are observed in the circuit do not mean anything, I only made a sketch in proteus so that they know what the circuit is like)

If you think that the design is not very efficient and you think that there is a better topology, could you please tell me.
I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to control motor speed or just activate/deactivate the motor? What happens when C2 is discharged?

Comment: Are you familiar with "thyristors"?

Comment: I could use thyristors, but I want to design this circuit